# SQLCipher error: sqlite3_key is undefined

Tags: encryption, console-application, sqlcipher

Using:

```
sqlite3_key(db, "test123", 7);
```

throws an ||sqlite3_key is undefined|| error, but I already added sqlite3.h file and it has that method. 
I realize that there is a comment whit this hint above.

```
** Specify the key for an encrypted database.  This routine should be
** called right after sqlite3_open().
**
** The code to implement this API is not available in the public release
** of SQLite.
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is likely not including the CFLAG `-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC` to make `sqlite3_key` available at compile time, please check that.  For more information on the SQLCipher build process, please see [this](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/) page.

Comment: Thanks Nick Parker, but in wich cmd goes the .configure code? VisualStudioCommandPromp, cmd or msys.bat?

Comment: Those instructions are specific to building SQLCipher from either Linux or OS X, not Windows.

Comment: And what about Windows?

Comment: @NickParker i have tried with sqlcipher on ubuntu. and it is working fine using pragma key. Is it correct to use same CFLAG for sqlite3 direct installation as an argument for ./configure? Actually i tried just after reading your comment using ./configure CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lcrypto" . But now it is giving undefined reference to sqlite3_key_v2 and sqlite3_rekey_v2. Do i have to pass any other CFLAGS? I know i am late to ask, but any pointer/link/keyword will be helpful.